# What HTTP headers do I need to stream an ASF file?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, streaming, http-headers

I have a simple PHP script that will either serve up a streaming ASF file or not, depending on whether you're logged in and have access to the file. It basically does this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: video/x-ms-asf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.asf"');
readfile('file.asf');

?>
```

This already works fine in Firefox; when you navigate to this file it starts the video streaming right away. But Internet Explorer is a different story. When I go to this link in IE, it consistently tries to download the file as if it were an attachment rather than streaming it in the browser. What I am missing that IE's getting hung up on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to add the `Content-Disposition`. Did you try removing it?

Comment: I'm not sure why this worked, but it worked. Setting Content-Disposition to "inline" is supposed to tell the browser explicitly not to download the file, but it seems IE doesn't handle that properly. So just removing that instruction worked!

Answer (score 1):

It look like that your IE or Media Player isn't correctly configured. Check this link [link text](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/howto/articles/webserver.aspx#webserver_topic2) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like your IE is configured to save a `.asf` file rather than stream it. Perhaps you can try opening a similar file on your local drive in IE to check whether it's configured to stream it.